# Problem with app router when used with nextra & i18n

Tags: next.js, i18next, app-router, nextra

I am using nextra docs in pages router and my main site on the app router, but when I tried to implement the i18n support for the nextra, I updated the nextconfig file, after that i am facing issues in the app directory routing, the pages in the app dir are not opening up(showing 404 error). What is the reason for this and how can I fix it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oks2f.png)

When i uncomment the commented lines from the next config, the app router breaks giving a 404 error, i am not able to use both pages router and the app router when i enable i18n init.
I was going through the middleware thing but couldn't find any solution, could you help me for the same